# Discord.py Slash Command Permissions

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently working on a Discord Bot that utilizes Discord.py as its backend and uses cogs for slash commands, I am currently attempting to implement a working ban function with slash command permissions to not allow a member without a certain permission to see it, but I couldn't figure a fool-proof solution for this to work. However, I was able to find a decorator that would make a permission required before running the command, however, it doesn't work like I expected it to. Any help is appreciated! I couldn't find any documentation that gives me my expected result, however I did find discord.js documentation for the result that I am expecting. https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/permissions.html#member-permissions

I have tried to use the

```
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
```

decorator to be able to do this, but it doesn't have my expected functionality of hiding the slash command if the user does not have the ban_members permission, here is my full code:

```
#cogs / admin/ ban.py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord, typing

class banUser(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.hybrid_command()
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True) 
    @commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def ban_user(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, reason: typing.Optional[str]):
        """
        Ban certain members from your server.
        """
        await member.ban(reason = reason)
        await ctx.reply(f"{member} has been successfully banned from the server.", ephemeral=True)
        em = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.from_rgb(0,0,255),title=f"**{member} has been banned from the server**.",description=f"{member} has been banned from the server for {reason}.")
        await ctx.send(embed=em)

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(banUser(client))
```